# How to build thrift4go?

Tags: go, thrift

I'm new in GO.
I have decide to use implementation of Thrift for Go.
After reading manual installation instruction steps I have 
downloaded last Thrift  0.9.0 from git and start building process:

My build script is follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
export THRIFT=$(pwd)/thrift
export THRIFT4GO=$(pwd)/thrift4go
export GOROOT=/usr

bash $THRIFT4GO/scripts/merge_and_build.sh -b

cd $THRIFT
#./cleanup.sh
./bootstrap.sh
./configure --with-go --without-python --without-csharp

make
if "$?" == "1"; then
    ln -s $THRIFT/lib/go/src/thrift $GOPATH/src/thrift
    go install thrift
fi
```

But make doesn't work well for GO, whereis the problem ?
I have correct installed GO with exported GOPATH variable in bash, "go install" worked for other projects.
I can't understand why GO can't find package.

```
Making all in go
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/user/projects/delkon/thrift/lib/go'
make  check-local
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/user/projects/delkon/thrift/lib/go'
go build -v -x thrift
WORK=/tmp/go-build548238117
src/thrift/tiostream_transport.go:23:2: import "bufio": cannot find package
src/thrift/tframed_transport.go:23:2: import "bytes": cannot find package
src/thrift/tmap.go:24:2: import "container/list": cannot find package
src/thrift/tjson_protocol.go:23:2: import "encoding/base64": cannot find package
src/thrift/tbinary_protocol.go:23:2: import "encoding/binary": cannot find package
src/thrift/tsimple_json_protocol.go:26:2: import "encoding/json": cannot find package
src/thrift/tapplication_exception.go:23:2: import "errors": cannot find package
src/thrift/tcompact_protocol.go:24:2: import "fmt": cannot find package
src/thrift/tbinary_protocol.go:24:2: import "io": cannot find package
src/thrift/ttransport.go:23:2: import "log": cannot find package
src/thrift/tbinary_protocol.go:25:2: import "math": cannot find package
src/thrift/tnonblocking_server_socket.go:23:2: import "net": cannot find package
src/thrift/thttp_client.go:24:2: import "net/http": cannot find package
src/thrift/thttp_client.go:25:2: import "net/url": cannot find package
src/thrift/ttransport.go:24:2: import "os": cannot find package
src/thrift/tmap.go:25:2: import "reflect": cannot find package
package thrift
imports runtime: import "runtime": cannot find package
src/thrift/tfield.go:23:2: import "sort": cannot find package
src/thrift/thttp_client.go:26:2: import "strconv": cannot find package
src/thrift/tbinary_protocol.go:26:2: import "strings": cannot find package
src/thrift/tnonblocking_socket.go:24:2: import "time": cannot find package
make[4]: *** [check-local] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/user/projects/delkon/thrift/lib/go'
make[3]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/projects/delkon/thrift/lib/go'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/projects/delkon/thrift/lib'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/projects/delkon/thrift'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thank you for any input
p.s
Arch linux (X86, 64)

**upd**
The problem was when thrift cloned from GIT, use https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/thrift/0.9.0/thrift-0.9.0.tar.gz version instead

Comment: Do you have `gccgo` or `gc` Go compiler toolchain? If `gc`: please add output of `go version` and `go env`.

Comment: go version go1.0.3
    GOARCH="amd64"
    GOBIN=""
    GOCHAR="6"
    GOEXE=""
    GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
    GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
    GOHOSTOS="linux"
    GOOS="linux"
    GOPATH="/home/user/projects/go"
    GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
    GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
    CGO_ENABLED="1

Comment: Seems OK to me. At which path did you cloned the thrift4go repository?

Comment: At some custom path, like /home/user/projects/thrift and thereis two dirs: thrift (original tar.gz) , thrift4go ( Go version )  ...... Where are you extract original thrift tar.gz ?

Comment: I downloaded the archive to `$GOPATH/src/github.com/pomack/` and then extracted it using the README.md command `tar xzvf thrift-0.9.0.tar.gz`, so it must should have been in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/pomack/thrift-0.9.0`, I believe. I'm starting to think there's something wrong with the Arch distribution compared to Ubuntu (desktop) 12.04 (that's what I have here). Can you try to repeat the steps on Ubuntu? (Possible also in VirtualBox etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to follow *exactly* all of the [Manual Installation](https://github.com/pomack/thrift4go/blob/master/README.md#manual-installation) steps with no problems whatsoever.

```
(12:49) jnml@fsc-r550:~$ go version
go version go1.0.3
(12:49) jnml@fsc-r550:~$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/home/jnml/bin"
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/jnml"
GOROOT="/home/jnml/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/home/jnml/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
(12:49) jnml@fsc-r550:~$
```

Note: I have cloned the thrift4go repository into `$GOPATH/src/github.com/pomack/thrift4go`. This is not mentioned in the README.md.

Comment: do you make tutorial (as descibed in Manual installation ) or just make ?

Comment: No, the last command I have tried is the last step of the 'Manual installation' section: `go install thrift` and it succeeded. Then I deleted the whole thing.

Comment: I have moved thrift4go to $GOPATH/src/github.com/pomack/thrift4go                                                          set GOROOT and GOPATH to correct one start configure --with-go && make I have Error in other place

Comment: Making all in tutorial
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/projects/delkon/thrift/tutorial'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/projects/delkon/thrift/tutorial'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/projects/delkon/thrift'
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: btw, go install thrift also worked and created $GOPATH/go/png/linux_arm64/thrift.a file

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas :-( Let me suggest to ask at the golang-nuts mailing list. Hopefully some of the dev guys can spot where's the problem.

Comment: I have used thrift from git trunk not from tar.gz

Comment: As I said, I followed the prescribed steps _exactly_, maybe you should try the same ;-)

Comment: Yes, I found the problem, it is in thrief from git trunk ! https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/thrift/0.9.0/thrift-0.9.0.tar.gz  - This is worked, but from git trunk not.     Thank you for your help.